# Load users from Active Directory using ADLDAP

Tags: php, active-directory, ldap, adldap

I'm using the ADLDAP library (http://adldap.sourceforge.net) to interact with Active Directory. I am using PHP. I would like to get all users from Active Directory and save them to array. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably want to do something like:

```
$adldap = new adLDAP();
$usernames = $adldap->user()->all();

$users = array();
foreach ($usernames as $username)
{
    $userInfo = $adldap->user()->infoCollection($username);
    $users[$username] = $userInfo;
}
```

the `all()` method is doumented [here](http://adldap.sourceforge.net/wiki/doku.php?id=documentation_user_functions).

Comment: is there a way to have only active (not disabled) users?

Comment: @Sirber: the `all()` method takes a `$search` parameter, which I believe can be used to filter the list.  It should be a regular LDAP filter I think.  Or you could just filter the results in the `for` loop on the `enabled` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the directory administrators would permit an LDAP client application to retrieve
all entries from a directory, extract the value of the attribute `namingContexts` from the root
DSE. The values of this attribute (it is multi-valued) are the naming contexts or suffixes that
this server supports. With this information, construct a search using:

- the naming context
- a size limit 0f 0 (no sizelimit)
- a time limit of 0 (unlimited time)
- a filter that will match all entries, for example, `(objectClass=*)` or `(&)`
- a scope sufficient to discover all entries, probably `subtree`
- a list of the attributes you require

Construct this search for each `namingContext`. Again, assuming that the directory
administrators will allow an LDAP client to search the entire directory, these searches will
result in responses that contain every entry.

There are many caveats such as:

- is this permitted by administrators?
- can your application grow big enough to handle the data (if not the Simple Paged Results
  mechanism may provide a solution).
- I have been told that AD imposes a size limit of 1000 on LDAP clients. Even if this is true,
  no LDAP client should be coded with knowledge of a directory infrastructure or vendor. Doing
  so results in poor, brittle code that is difficult to maintain. All LDAP clients must be coded
  to the standards imposed by the LDAP Directorate at the IETF.

For more information, see:

- [LDAP: The Root DSE](http://ff1959.wordpress.com/2011/04/11/the-root-dse-is-that-entry-with-zero-rdns-and-contains-information-about-the-directory-server/)
- [LDAP: Search Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-search-best-practices.html)
- [LDAP: Programming Practices](http://www.ldapguru.info/ldap/ldap-programming-practices.html)

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand.
I'm looking for a way to get all AD users from AD, and store them into array using PHP.